# Is there a direct way to retarget a trigger to a different table

Tags: oracle

I am working on some Enterpriseware backed by an Oracle 11.2 database. The enterpriseware has some table named `T` in its datamodel. I found a table named `OLDT` along in this datamodel, probably created by some script run in production by the previous maintainers. This `OLDT`table has a trigger `TRIG` associated to it, which was clearly intended to be attached to `T`, and is coded in the style of the enterpriseware. I suspect this is the result of some script renaming `T` to `OLDT`, and recreating `T` after that.

My question is : is there a direct way, in Oracle, to retarget a trigger to another table, or is dropping and recreating the trigger the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Following [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/485769?start=0&tstart=0) thread, you can view a source code of your trigger. Then copy its source code, change what you need to change in it (table name), drop existing trigger and create a new one.

From the thread, try this:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER','MY_TRG',user) 
from dual;
```

or this

```
select text 
from all_source 
where name='&trig_name' and type='TRIGGER';
```

Comment: So you mean, there is no `ALTER TRIGGER TRIG SET TABLE T` kind of magic?

Comment: I think you understand that such use case is ultra rare? Different tables are in general not compatible at all to support foreign triggers.

Comment: Why are you so concerned about doing it with an ALTER statement?  You have already spent more time on this thread than it would take to drop and create.  If you'd have simply done the obvious, your task would be completed already.

Comment: The question was "is there a way to do it directly", and I believe it is a legitimate one. As far as I searched, it has not been asked. I understand that this use case endangers no user data, so can be safely done through DROP-CREATE, provided that no other fix deployment changes the code of the trigger by the time my fix gets into production. The ALTER syntax could have existed, and could be a feature that would contribute to Oracle lifting themselves slightly above the strictly-necessary.

Comment: I edited the question to be more in line with what I intended to ask. Thank you for your time, both of you.